# Use custom object inside react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I guess I really don't get the concept. I want to create a custom object inside a react component. The custom objects itself creates new elements.

For example: I have a custom object

```
function LabelEditor(canvas, width, height) {

    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.canvas.width = width;
    this.canvas.height = height;
    this.canvas.id = 'mainEditor';
    this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    console.log('hi ' + this.canvas.width  + ' / ' + this.canvas.height);

    this.getCanvas = function() {
        return this.canvas;
    };
}
```

Now I want to access the properties, functions and the elements created by this object inside a react component, something like this:

```
var Editor = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>{this.props.editor.getCanvas()}</div>
        );
    }
});

React.render(
    <Editor editor={new LabelEditor(React.DOM.canvas, 500, 500)} />,
    document.getElementsByTagName('editor')[0]
);
```

But every combination of props, state and something have failed by now.

The idea behind this is, I want to build an editor with fabric.js, but want to use it inside a `React.js` application. The `fabric.js` functionality will be wrapped inside a custom object with an interface to control the actions. I want to use React only as the visual part, the `LabelEditor`-object will as a controller, and the the `fabric.js` as some sort of model, providing a drawable canvas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is how I would structure the code ([See this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jawice/1/edit?html,js,output) for a working demo). Basically, Editor component renders `<canvas>` and you would instantiate your LabelEditor in `componentDidMount()`. You use `React.findDOMNode()` because `<canvas>` in `render()` represents a virtual DOM and you would need to find the corresponding DOM. Now, `LabelEditor` can do the drawing.

```
function LabelEditor(canvas, width, height) {
  this.canvas = canvas;
  this.canvas.width = width;
  this.canvas.height = height;
  this.canvas.id = 'mainEditor';

  // Draw something
  var ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = "#A0EBDD"
  ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 150, 150);
}

var Editor = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    var canvas = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.canvas);
    this._editor = new LabelEditor(canvas, this.props.width, this.props.height);
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <canvas ref="canvas"></canvas>
    );
  }
});

React.render(
  <Editor width={500} height={500} />,
  document.getElementById('editor')
);
```

Comment: Oh! thank you. this works exactly as I want. Now I can go on and try new stuff.