# React component owning objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Is it recommended in React component to own other objects ? Is there some disadvantage of doing so ? I see it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31711314/use-custom-object-inside-react-component)

and here is my example:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Utility from './Utility';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        message: 'Hello',
        name: 'John!'
    };
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.utility = new Utility();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>{this.props.message}, {this.props.name} {this.utility.getText()}</h1>
        );
    }
}
```

Utility would be some class providing more functionality to the component. Most of the examples I've checked don't have this kind of things. If it is fine to use then would it be better to instantiate in the constructor or in mount function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter. I would prefer to do it in the constructor as I feel this is more of a initialization process. The only way react lifecycle methods communicate with each other is by either looking up in the state(or props) or the `this` variable.

Most of the times putting random things in the state only causes performance issues by calling the render again and again, so you should try to move these variables to the this like:

```
this.utility = new Utility();
```

Also if this is something that is being used at multiple places consider passing it in the props from the parent. This way you can use the same initialized object everywhere in the children components(But that depends on your use case).

Comment: I guess with react applications the design of the application becomes even more important just to avoid bloating unnecessary props while passing still important ones to right places.

Comment: This really depends on the use case

Answer (score 2):

Since , it is an utility, it is recommended to use **singleton design pattern**.

Indeed, I spent almost 6 months i was working like your snippet shows.

However, I am now switching to **singleton design pattern** as following:

### Utility.js

```
class Utility {
   // methods

}

export const utility = new Utility();
export default  Utility; // i know, you are using only this .. use also the above  to export the singleton
```

Then , in your React Component :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {utility} from './Utility'; // import with "{utility}" not "Utility"

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        message: 'Hello',
        name: 'John!'
    };
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
      // this.utility = new Utility(); <-- no need 
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>{this.props.message}, {this.props.name} {utility.getText()}</h1>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point! Would make sense in one case I'm working right now.

Comment: Welcome @Janne .. By the way, all the following   `constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.utility = new Utility();
    }` can be replaced by `utility = new Utility();` . it is not related to my answer ,, but it is related to ES7 since your are already using `static` attributes inside the class .

Comment: Tried singleton approach in my project and it is perfect solution for two utility classes 

Comment: congrats! 